# replacing a particular pattern only in a specific column using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

i have a file

```
$ cat file1
1 2 lallu.3
3 4 lallu.5
4 5 lallu.6
```

my output file should be

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
4 5 6
```

i want to replace lallu. in 3rd column to ""

I have tried the following in awk

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 } | awk '$3 ~ /lallu\./ { $3 = ""}1 '
```

this seems to be not working . can u plaese help.

Comment: wt the script you tried: what do you think that script is doing? It doesn't make any sense at all so I'm curious what you thought those language constructs meant so maybe we can set you straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use awk's sub funtion.

```
awk '{sub(/lallu\./, "", $3)}1' file
```

If you want to remove more than one `lallu.` substring on the same column, then use `gsub` instead of `sub` .(ie, replace `sub` with `gsub`) in the above.